# Generate compile_commands.json for autotools and conan based c++ project

Tags: c++, cmake, autotools, conan

I have a autotools and conan based c++ project based project and I don't know what has to be done so that compile_commands.json is generated.

In case of cmake and conan based project,
`cmake.definitions['CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS'] = "ON"` in the conanfile.py does the trick.

But what about autotools and conan based c++ project?

Comment: https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks a lot for your comment. But how do we pass this info from conan file. We need to call 'bear make'. But in conan file, we call make method of AutoToolsBuildEnvironment. How do we add bear in front of make?

Comment: Just set `make_program` when calling `make`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks for your comment. Could you please share a link to an example?

Comment: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/build_helpers/autotools.html#make

Comment: That integration is legacy, no longer maintained. Recommended to use https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/gnu.html tools instead.